# String index out of range and Totals using input data

Tags: java

I need some help with the code below. I am trying to loop the program until the user selects 'N' and then I want to display the totals for lemonade sold in oz and total cookies and shirts of each kind.

I put in a while loop to loop the program but I get an error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at edu.kirkland5.SnackStand.main(SnackStand.java:43)

If anyone could help me with what I would need to do to accomplish these two things I would appreciate it greatly. Thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userName = "";
    int lemonaid = 0;
    double OZ12_PRICE = 1.50;
    double OZ16_PRICE = 2.00;
    char cookies = 0;
    double COOKIES_OAT= .75;
    double COOKIES_CHOCO= .75;
    char tshirt = 0;
    double TSHIRT_Y = 15.00;
    double TSHIRT_N = 8.00;
    char item;
    char answer = 0;

    System.out.println("Hello. May I ask your name?");
    userName = input.nextLine();



    while (answer != 'N') 
    {
    System.out.println("Welcome " +userName +". Would you like to purchase something? (Y/N) ");
    answer = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
    answer = Character.toUpperCase(answer);

    System.out.println(" ***Lemonaid Stand Program***");
    System.out.println("=======================================");
    System.out.println("Enter purchase item, first letter only.");
    System.out.println("Lemonaid, Cookies, T-shirt.");
    System.out.println("Enter Q to Quit.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter an item or Q to quit (L,C,T,Q)");
    item = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
    item = Character.toUpperCase(item);

    while (item != 'L' && item != 'C' && item != 'T' && item != 'Q')
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        System.out.println("Please enter an item, or Q to quit. (L,C,T,Q): ");
        item = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
            item = Character.toUpperCase(item);     
    }

        if (item == 'L')
        {
        System.out.println("What size would you like?");
        System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "12oz.", OZ12_PRICE);
        System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "16oz.", OZ16_PRICE);
        System.out.println("Input the number only.");
        lemonaid = input.nextInt();

        while (lemonaid != 12 && lemonaid != 16)

        {System.out.println("I'm sorry. Please only input an 16 or 12.");
        lemonaid=input.nextInt();
        }
            if (lemonaid == 12)
            {
                Sales_Header(); 
            System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "12oz.", OZ12_PRICE);
            }

            else if (lemonaid == 16)
            {
                Sales_Header();
            System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "16oz.", OZ16_PRICE);
            }

            else
            {
            }

        }//end If = L
        else if (item == 'C')
        {
            System.out.println("What type would you like?");
            System.out.printf("%-14s%10.2f\n", "Oatmeal", COOKIES_OAT);
            System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "Chocolate Chip", COOKIES_CHOCO);
            System.out.println("Input the first letter only. (O/C)");
            cookies = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
                cookies = Character.toUpperCase(cookies);

            while (cookies != 'O' && cookies != 'C')

            {
            System.out.println("I'm sorry. Please only input an 'O' or 'C'.");
            cookies = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
            cookies = Character.toUpperCase(cookies);
            }

            if (cookies == 'O')
            {
                Sales_Header();
            System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "Oatmeal", COOKIES_OAT);
            }

            else if (cookies == 'C')
            {
                    Sales_Header();
            System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "Chocolate Chip", COOKIES_CHOCO);
            }

            else
            {
            }

        }// end else if = C

        else if (item == 'T')
            {
            System.out.println("Would you like that shirt autographed?");
            System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "With autograph", TSHIRT_Y);
            System.out.printf("%-10s%11.2f\n", "W/O autograph", TSHIRT_N);
            System.out.println("Select Yes or No (Y/N)");
            tshirt = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
            tshirt = Character.toUpperCase(tshirt);

            while (tshirt != 'Y' && tshirt != 'N')
            {
                System.out.println("I'm sorry. Please only input an 'Y' or 'N'.");
                tshirt = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
                tshirt = Character.toUpperCase(tshirt);
            }
                if (tshirt == 'Y')
                {
                    Sales_Header();
                System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "With autograph", TSHIRT_Y);
                }

                else if (tshirt == 'N')
                {
                    Sales_Header();
                System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "W/O autograph", TSHIRT_N);
                }

                else
                {
                }
        }//end else if T

        else if (item == 'Q')
        {
            System.out.println("Main Menu.");
        }

        else
        {
        }

}//End while loop
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception comes from the nextInt() call because it does not "eat" the line. I have quickly created variables to let you sum the number of items sold but in practice you'd need a better structure to your code. You can create classes for your items that will contain the descriptions, the prices and the quantity sold. Your while loop at the top has an issue because you are doing (while answer != N) before getting answer. So the solution is to initialize answer before the loop, then read it again at the end of the loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String userName = "";
        int lemonaid = 0;
        double OZ12_PRICE = 1.50;
        double OZ16_PRICE = 2.00;
        char cookies = 0;
        double COOKIES_OAT = .75;
        double COOKIES_CHOCO = .75;
        char tshirt = 0;
        double TSHIRT_Y = 15.00;
        double TSHIRT_N = 8.00;
        char item;
        char answer = 0;

        int numLemonaid = 0;
        int totalOz = 0;
        int numCookies = 0;
        int numTShirts = 0;

        System.out.println("Hello. May I ask your name?");
        userName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Welcome " + userName + ". Would you like to purchase something? (Y/N) ");
        answer = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        answer = Character.toUpperCase(answer);

        while (answer != 'N') {
            System.out.println(" ***Lemonaid Stand Program***");
            System.out.println("=======================================");
            System.out.println("Enter purchase item, first letter only.");
            System.out.println("Lemonaid, Cookies, T-shirt.");
            System.out.println("Enter Q to Quit.");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter an item or Q to quit (L,C,T,Q)");
            item = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
            item = Character.toUpperCase(item);

            while (item != 'L' && item != 'C' && item != 'T' && item != 'Q') {
                System.out.println("Invalid input.");
                System.out.println("Please enter an item, or Q to quit. (L,C,T,Q): ");
                item = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
                item = Character.toUpperCase(item);
            }

            if (item == 'L') {
                System.out.println("What size would you like?");
                System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "12oz.", OZ12_PRICE);
                System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "16oz.", OZ16_PRICE);
                System.out.println("Input the number only.");
                lemonaid = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();

                numLemonaid++;

                while (lemonaid != 12 && lemonaid != 16)

                {
                    System.out.println("I'm sorry. Please only input an 16 or 12.");
                    lemonaid = input.nextInt();
                    input.nextLine();
                }
                totalOz += lemonaid;
                if (lemonaid == 12) {
                    // Sales_Header();
                    System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "12oz.", OZ12_PRICE);
                }

                else if (lemonaid == 16) {
                    /// Sales_Header();
                    System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "16oz.", OZ16_PRICE);
                }

                else {
                }

            } // end If = L
            else if (item == 'C') {
                System.out.println("What type would you like?");
                System.out.printf("%-14s%10.2f\n", "Oatmeal", COOKIES_OAT);
                System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "Chocolate Chip", COOKIES_CHOCO);
                System.out.println("Input the first letter only. (O/C)");
                cookies = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
                cookies = Character.toUpperCase(cookies);
                numCookies++;

                while (cookies != 'O' && cookies != 'C')

                {
                    System.out.println("I'm sorry. Please only input an 'O' or 'C'.");
                    cookies = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
                    cookies = Character.toUpperCase(cookies);
                }

                if (cookies == 'O') {
                    // Sales_Header();
                    System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "Oatmeal", COOKIES_OAT);
                }

                else if (cookies == 'C') {
                    // Sales_Header();
                    System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "Chocolate Chip", COOKIES_CHOCO);
                }

                else {
                }

            } // end else if = C

            else if (item == 'T') {
                System.out.println("Would you like that shirt autographed?");
                System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "With autograph", TSHIRT_Y);
                System.out.printf("%-10s%11.2f\n", "W/O autograph", TSHIRT_N);
                System.out.println("Select Yes or No (Y/N)");
                tshirt = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
                tshirt = Character.toUpperCase(tshirt);

                numTShirts++ ;

                while (tshirt != 'Y' && tshirt != 'N') {
                    System.out.println("I'm sorry. Please only input an 'Y' or 'N'.");
                    tshirt = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
                    tshirt = Character.toUpperCase(tshirt);
                }
                if (tshirt == 'Y') {
                    // Sales_Header();
                    System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "With autograph", TSHIRT_Y);
                }

                else if (tshirt == 'N') {
                    // Sales_Header();
                    System.out.printf("%-10s%10.2f\n", "W/O autograph", TSHIRT_N);
                }

                else {
                }
            } // end else if T

            else if (item == 'Q') {
                System.out.println("Main Menu.");

            }

            else {
            }

            System.out.println("Welcome " + userName + ". Would you like to purchase something? (Y/N) ");
            answer = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
            answer = Character.toUpperCase(answer);
        } // end while

        System.out.println("Lemonaid: " + numLemonaid + "(" + totalOz +"Oz)") ;
        System.out.println("Shirts: " + numTShirts) ;
        System.out.println("Cookies: " + numCookies) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a huge help! Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

To get a single character from Standard Input (a/k/a STDIN a/k/a a keyboard), you can take one of two approaches:

```
char tshirt = (char) System.in.read(); //Takes one character, casts to "char"
```

Or you can use a method from Scanner like so:

```
char thsirt = scanner.next("."); //Takes exactly one character
```

This should ensure that you don't have to deal with an `IndexOutofBounds` error.